# Vuejs 3 Composition API - Reference defined object inside a function or compute properties

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vuejs and I'm trying to figure out where I'm wrong

this is my sample code:

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const count = ref(0)
const filter = ref({
  caso1: true,
  caso2: false,
  caso3: true
})

function increment() {
  count.value++;
  this.filter.caso1 = !this.filter.caso1
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="increment">{{ count }}</button>
  <p>
    {{ filter }}
  </p>
</template>
```

when the code runs and I click on the button, it display an error

> "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')" and I'm not able to figure out why and how do I have to change it.

I imagine it is a very simple task but I'm reading documentation and tutorial to implement my Vuejs knowledge.

Comment: @ericmp Doesn't he need `.value` too? E.G `filter.value.caso1`

Comment: yeah, sorry, forget my previous answer, idk what u r trying to do but replace `this.filter` by `filter.value` in the script setup side. As `filter` is a ref, u need to access its value using `.value`